# Finding of an example of a metric space.

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification

Find such a metric space (other than the discrete metric space) that boundary of every subset is empty.

If I take usual metric on $\mathbb{N}$

As, for every subset $\{x_1,x_2,\cdot\cdot\cdot,x_n\}$,
We get $B(x_i,\frac{1}{2}) \cap (\mathbb{N}\setminus \{x_1,x_2,\cdot\cdot\cdot,x_n\})= \varnothing$

And, for an infinite subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$ , same logic is also applicable i.e.,  $B(x,\frac{1}{2}) \cap (\mathbb{N}\setminus A)= \varnothing$ ( where, $x$ runs over for every element in $A$)

So, every subset has empty boundary.

Please verify someone.....

Comment: Well $\mathbb{N}$ with usual metric is discrete so indeed every subset has empty boundary but you ask for a nondiscrete example.

Comment: @Theo Bendit what would be non discrete metric space example satisfying above? Does there actually any exist?

Comment: No, Antoine's right: all such metric spaces do indeed generate the discrete topology. I was somehow thinking in my head that only the open sets had empty boundary.

Comment: @Theo Bendit so there doesn't exist any non discrete metric space example satisfying above(means having every subset with empty boundary), right?

Comment: Well, to clarify, the discrete metric on a set $X$ has a very specific definition:$$d(x, y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \neq y \\0 & \text{if } x = y.\end{cases}$$The usual metric on $\Bbb{N}$ is not the same metric as this. BUT, they do generate the same topology: the discrete topology. So, as you've shown, there are multiple metrics (not just the discrete metric) that can produce this empty boundary condition, but as Antoine has shown, all such metrics generate the same discrete topology. So, your "technical" example (as I called it before) is as good an example as we can hope to get.

Comment: @Theo Bendit thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Every topological space with the property that every subset has empty boundary must be discrete.
Indeed, any non-closed subset has nonempty boundary, so all subsets must be closed, i.e. the topology is discrete.

Comment: Thanks for response,.but you sure that there doesn't exist any non discrete metric space satisfying the given condition?

Comment: If technically we see my example is not discrete metric space example, but it is equivalent to discrete metric space.  And equivalent can't mean that the same, right?

Comment: Well it depends on what you mean by a "discrete metric space". As mentionned by Theo Bendit there are examples that don't literally have the discrete metric but all examples must be topologically discrete (all sets are open and closed).

Comment: Actually,.I want a non discrete metric space example satisfying above(mean having every subset with empty boundary). Please provide.

Comment: I know that, but can you define what you mean by "non discrete metric space"? In my understanding of "discrete" such an example doesn't exist.

Comment: So, please tell why there doesn't exist a non discrete metric space having every subset with empty boundary. Please add this in the answer with little more decribed. I need that specially.

Comment: Read my answer, that's exactly what I explain.